# Navigationbar not visible during runtime

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

Agh, it seems iOS7 has changed the way we use the navigation bars are status bar.

I have a UINavigationController with one view (UITableView) as my root view controller. In the IB I can see the nag bar and the title. When I run the app - the navigation bar is not there and my cells overlap in the status bar.

Can someone tell me whats going on?

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you using IB or storyboard?

Comment: Have you map outlets?

Comment: Nope - but I found out what the issue was and added it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution to the problem. Incase anyone else has this issue. I was loading the UITableView controller directly in code. I used a StoryboardID on the UITableViewController and not the UINavigationController. As soon as I changed it - everything worked as per normal.

Silly little things...